# Problema al subir archivo

Tags: php

El formulario para subir un archivo usando **PHP** es este:

```
<form action="subir_file.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE debe preceder al campo de entrada del fichero -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2097152" />
    <!-- El nombre del elemento de entrada determina el nombre en el array $_FILES -->
    Enviar este fichero: <input name="file" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Subir">
    <input type="submit" name="cerrar" value="Cerrar">
</form>
```

En el archivo PHP tengo:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', NULL);  // Lo agregué para evitar el mensaje de WARNING, pero igual se muestra....
if(!isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "VACIO";
    exit;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_FILES); //Cuando el archivo es muy grande no muestra nada.
```

Estoy probando la recepción del archivo de trabajo que normalmente pesa menos de 1MB.
Quiero restringir que no se suba un archivo extremadamente grande y que en el lado del servidor me permita validar esto para mostrar un mensaje de "Archivo muy grande".
Pero al hacerlo me arroja este mensaje y el array no contiene nada:

```
Warning: POST Content-Length of 191932818 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0
Array
(
)
```

Pero si el array llega vacío debería poder mostrar mi mensaje personalizado, pero siempre se muestra el `Warning: POST Content-Lenght...`. Y eso no debería ocurrir.
Y para no mostrar el Warning agregué esto:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', NULL);
```

o

```
ini_set('error_reporting', 0);
```

o

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Y ninguno funciona. Sigue mostrando el `Warning`.

Comment: Eso tiene pinta de que el max-post-size o algún otro parámetro en el php.ini están por debajo del tamaño de tu archivo. Verifica :) Y tendrías que validar del lado del cliente, antes de intentar enviárselo al servidor para que PHP lo lea... porque si el php.ini dice que máximo 2MB, no va a subir y no verás nada

Comment: Mi archivo no pesa mucho (500KB), Pero quiero restringir con un mensaje en caso se trate de cargar un archivo pesado.

Comment: Pero en la pregunta dices que "si subo un archivo extremadamente grande,..." y por eso comenté lo que está ahí. Entonces, ¿te preocupa el caso de archivo muy grande? O cuál es tu pregunta? Recuerda que puedes [edit] si lo requieres para modificar o añadir lo que desees.

Comment: @Alfabravo edité pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba así:

```html
<form action="subir_file.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        Enviar este fichero:
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" value="subir" onchange="javascript: validateFile(this)">
    </form>
    

    <script>
        function validateFile(obj){
            var uploadFile = obj.files[0];
    
            //VALIDA QUE EL NAV PUEDA LEER ARCHIVOS
            if (!window.FileReader) {
                alert('El navegador no soporta la lectura de archivos');
                return;
            }
    
            //VALIDA QUE SOLO SE PUEDAN SUBIR ARCHIVOS PDF (Puedes cambiar este dato u omitir la validacion)
            if (!(/\.(PDF|pdf)$/i).test(uploadFile.name)) {        
                alert("error. Comprueba la extensión del archivo");
                document.getElementById("file").value="";
                return false;
            }else{
                //VALIDA QUE SOLO SUBA ARCHIVOS MENORES A 2MB
                if (uploadFile.size > 2097152){                 
                        alert("error . El limite es 2mb");
                        document.getElementById("file").value="";
                        return false;
                }else{
                        alert("Archivo aceptado :3 ");
                        return true;             
                }
            }  
        }
    </script>
```

Este código es para validar del lado del cliente que no pueden subir mas de 2MB, de esta forma evitas que el servidor tenga que validar el tamaño y el tipo de archivo.

Comment: Excelente la recomendación final para evitarle carga al server. Tener en cuenta también, que por temas de seguridad, la validación del lado del cliente puede verse vulnerada.